# How to restrict html body width when not displayed on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, html, css

I have set up a web page to look good on the small screen of an iPhone, but when viewed on the desktop, and going right across the width of the browser, it looks terrible.  Is there a way I can restrict the width to say, 480px when viewed on a big screen?

I tried

```
   body {     
          margin-left:auto;
          margin-right:auto;
          max-width:480px;
    }
```

but it seems to just set the width at 480px, even on an iPhone on portrait mode.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Media Types](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html) are what you're looking for.